# In my VS code and Android Studio I don't see a line app package inside the folder Androidmanifest.xml

Tags: package

No package name in Android manifest.xml folder

Android>apps>src>main>Android manifest

I need the package address to connect with Google firebase
For backend purpose.

But in both IDE their is no package name

Please help